# Is there api or gate to access credit card bill based on credit card number

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

is there way to obtain credit card bill (e.g how much, when and where you spent) based on just credit card name,cvc,number,expiry date ?
I'm mainly interested in API (such you provide id data they provide complete list) or at least web-based application

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes and no. First, I say yes because when I go to my Bank's website, I have access to all this information. That being said, we all know that all our single transactions are stored somwhere in a data base for a couple of month, then it's achived and stored in bunkers or somthing high security. Even for my own bank, it's impossible to have my transaction record past 60 days. I can, but I have to make a demand and pay for the guy that retreives it for me! Finally, I would say no, because that would be a enormous breach in the bank's system! They can ensure you (and that is not 100% real) that only you and the bank will have access to you transaction history.

But, if you work for a bank (which I doubt because you asked the question) you have access to all this. You don't need an API. It's only a data base. If you have access, you can query it!

Answer (score 0):

There better not be.

Name on the card, CVV Number and Expiry Date are the same 3 fields you have to enter to purchase anything on most e-commerce websites. If any of those websites could suddenly access my entire credit card bill, I would not be pleased.

Or in other words, no.